# Не работает окно с кнопками

Tags: ооп, java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class ButtonDemo implements ActionListener{

    public JLabel jlab;
    ButtonDemo(){
        JFrame jfrm=new JFrame("Frame!");
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setBackground(new Color(4654987));
        jfrm.setSize(235, 90);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton Button1=new JButton("Button1");
        JButton Button2=new JButton("Button2");
        Button1.addActionListener(this);
        Button2.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.add(Button1);
        jfrm.add(Button2);
        jlab=new JLabel("LABEL!!!");
        jfrm.add(jlab);
        }
        public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Button1")){
                jlab.setText("Pres 1");
                }
            else{
                jlab.setText("Pres 2");
                }
            }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    new ButtonDemo();
                    }
                });
        }
}
```

Не хочет создавать экземпляр (последняя строчка).
Пишет мол сделайте нельзя инициализировать.

Если убрать абстракт, то пишет, что необх. осуществить метод ActionPerfotmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно не работает. Для чего у вас ButtonDemo реализует ActionListener? Мне кажется, вы просто не знаете, что делаете ))

UPD: Во-первых, Java case-sensitive. Вы создали метод ActionPerformed, а надо actionPerformed. ЗАмените одну букву и будет компилироваться. Но работать не будет.

Во-вторых, надо сделать setVisible(true), чтобы форма появилась иначе программа сразу же завершится как только запустится.

Comment: Делаю по Шилдту(таки не знаю)

Comment: а чем там эта реализация мешает?? просто вешается слушатель на класс

Comment: А надо знать. Думать, а не с книжки копировать.

Comment: Gnom, ты сам хоть что-то знаешь, или можешь только других обливать ___________________?

Gorets прав

Comment: Мой комментарий остаётся в силе. Разберитесь сначала что и зачем вы реализуте. В каждой букве, которую вы скопировали с книжки разберитесь: почему она тут и зачем. А потом уже на других наезжать будете. Мы здесь не на моём трибунале, чтобы мои поступки оценивать.
На ваш вопрос уже ответили: вы получаете ошибку потому что делаете ерунду. Если вы утверждаете, что скопировали с книжки, то вы значит комментарии к нему не прочитали.

Comment: 2Gorets: оно мешает тем, что не отвечает никаким целям. Давайте к каждому классу целую телегу implements писать.. так, для красоты :))

Comment: Просто скажите как исправить.Я разобрался и по-моему, все разумно

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли(про setVisible забыл)

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, класс же абстрактный.

Comment: а где у тебя тут унаследование?